# Enumeración: Mil millón vs. Billón

Tags: diferencias-regionales, números, matemáticas

En inglés, se dice "one billion" para la cantidad 10<sup>9</sup> (1,000,000,000).  Pero en español, he oído la cantidad "mil millones" para la misma cantidad (hasta en los periódicos).  Casi nunca he oído la palabra "billón" para decir 10<sup>9</sup>.

¿Dónde en el mundo suele decir "mil millones" en vez de "billón" en español?  ¿Dónde se dice "mil millones"? ¿Cuánto significa un billón?  ¿Será un billón equivalente a un millón de millones (10<sup>12</sup>)?

¿No hay un lugar donde se use "un billón" para 10<sup>9</sup>?

Comment: Mil millones se puede decir *millardo*.

Comment: Nótese que no todos los angloparlantes entienden "billion" como "mil millones", depende más de la región que del idioma.

Comment: [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milliard) on Wikipedia is relevant: "Most Spanish-language countries and regions use the long scale with 10^9 = mil millones"

Comment: @Nico: Gracias Nico.  El articulo explica mucho en cuanto a diferencias en todo el mundo!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Según el [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=billon)

> #### billón.
>
> Voz procedente del francés *billion*, ‘un millón de millones (10<sup>12</sup>)’. **Es inaceptable su empleo en español con el sentido de ‘mil millones’, que es el que tiene la palabra *billion* en el inglés americano.** Para este último sentido, debe emplearse la voz *millardo* (→ [millardo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Je1pVeggzD66DxjYzt)), procedente también del francés, o la equivalencia española *mil millones*.

Al menos en Cuba usamos:

- billón para 10<sup>12</sup>
- mil millones para 10<sup>9</sup>

En Colombia se usa de la misma manera

---

- millón es 10<sup>6</sup> → `1 000 000`
- **mil millones** ó millardo es 10<sup>9</sup> → `1 000 000 000`
- billón (un millón de millones) es 10<sup>12</sup> → `1 000 000 000 000`
- trillón (un millón de billones) es 10<sup>18</sup> → `1 000 000 000 000 000 000`

> En lo adelante no aparecen en el diccionario ya que no son de uso común estas palabras

- cuatrillón (un millón de trillones) es 10<sup>24</sup> → `1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000`
- quintillón (un millón de cuatrillones) es 10<sup>30</sup> → `1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000`
- sextillón (un millón de quintillones ) es 10<sup>36</sup> → `1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000`
- septillón (un millón de sextillón) es 10<sup>42</sup>
- octillón (un millón de septillón) es 10<sup>48</sup>
- nonillón (un millón de octillón) es 10<sup>54</sup>
- decillón (un millón de nonillón) es 10<sup>60</sup>

---

Interesante link aportado por @Nico en los comentarios (Español):

[http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalas_numéricas_larga_y_corta#Comparación_entre_la_escala_larga_y_la_corta](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalas_num%C3%A9ricas_larga_y_corta#Comparaci%C3%B3n_entre_la_escala_larga_y_la_corta)

Comment: Entonces, la regla de enumeracion es exponencial?  Es decir que 'un trillon' sera un billon de billones (10^24) y un quadrillon sera un trillon de trillones (10^48)?

Comment: van aumentando de 6 en 6

Comment: @Paul, no, un trillón es un millón de billones, o 10^18 (http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trill%C3%B3n). En España también se entiende un billón como un millón de millones.

Comment: Que curioso que en Espanol, se aumenta 6 en 6 mientras se aumenta 3 en 3 en ingles.  Es comun la regla 6 en 6 en todas las lenguas romanticas?  O es una peculiaridad de Espanol?

Comment: Sera mil billones (10^15) un *billardo* (y etc...)?

Comment: No creo que sea así lo del billardo, es más recomedable escribir estos números en notación cientifica (10^15), en cuanto a lo del 6 en 6, me parece que el frances, de ahi en fuera no estoy seguro. según este articulo en alemania se usa como en el español http://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-61424,00.html

Comment: por ejemplo 3 mil billones => `3x10^15`

Comment: @JoulSauron gracias, por la edición

Comment: @Paul, es una particularidad del inglés que se aumente de 3 en 3. Aunque históricamente se vaciló entre un uso y otro en francés, y también entre distintas variedades del inglés…

Comment: En todo el mundo hispanohablante tiene que ser igual pero al parecer en Puerto Rico al ser parte de Estados Unidos puede variar el significado pero aún cuando el diccionario recomiende millardo lo más probable es que NADIE, de verdad, NADIE, te entienda, a menos que sea un erudito en el tema.

Comment: @JaimeCruzTriana es cierto rara vez he escuchado millardo, mil millones es lo común. Yo vivo en USA y el problema que mas enfrento es el de los separadores `,` para los miles en ingles que hasta las publicaciones en español lo usan aqui

Comment: @Paul, en portugués siendo romance se usa el billón «americano» en Brasil (pero en Portugal no, es algo más regional que otra cosa). En Rumanía también se usa. [Aquí tienes una lista por países](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales).

Answer (score 5):

Como ya han indicado, un billón es un millón de millones y no mil millones. Para "mil millones" existe la palabra *millardo* pero en España se usa muy raramente (solo recuerdo haberla visto una vez en los medios).

Sin embargo, en ambientes técnicos y periodísticos es frecuente que se dé el error, al hacer una traducción literal del inglés, de hablar de billones en lugar de miles de millones (prueba a buscar "siete billones de personas" en Google). No obstante, son *errores* y no un cambio de uso en el lenguaje.

A veces he visto en áreas donde abundan las malas traducciones y se lee (y escribe) "a la defensiva" las expresiones "billones americanos" o "billones ingleses" y "billones españoles" para deshacer la ambigüedad, pero tampoco creo que esté extendido.

Answer (score 5):

Añado al resto de respuestas que, en inglés británico, un billón ha sido históricamente un millón de millones (10<sup>12</sup>), al igual que en castellano o en francés.

Otra cosa es que, de manera relativamente reciente y por influencia estadounidense haya aumentado el uso de billion como 10<sup>9</sup>.

**Fuente:** http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-many-is-a-billion

Comment: Excelente fuente +1